# Important About list View

Tags: c#

i have two form

first form have 3 textbox

1- for name
2- for age
3- for e-mail

second form have list view with three columns 
1- for name 
2- for age
3- for e-mail

i want when i complete the data of the three textbox in the first item and click on abutton
the data saved in the list view and when i enter  data again the lisst view add the new data to it without removing the old data on it

Comment: What view technology are you using?  ASP.Net? WinForms? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at .net datasources, create a new datasource and then databind() to the listview, when you add a new item, add it to the datasource and then refresh the listbox on the second form.